# App crashing when trying to send notification to a single device from firebase

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to send Firebase notification to a single device and for that I have retrieved the `FCM registration token` using the code below:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

Here is `MyFirebaseMessagingService.java` file's code:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    public void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to send Firebase notification while the app is still on screen, it is crashing giving this error multiple times: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI: content://com.android.contacts/phone_lookup/?encrypt=%20%3C%202, calling user: com.android.mms:10015, calling package:com.android.mms`

I really don't know what's going wrong here!

Please let me know.

Comment: Can you add the entire stack trace? I'd like to see where this originates.

Answer (score 2):

Try Debugging your onMessageReceived(), you must be getting remoteMessage.getNotification() = null if you are not sending a notification block in your push:

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        // Check if remoteMessage.getNotification() == null ??
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()); 

        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
```

Also update your question with full error log.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the line "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" in your app's build.gradle lies at the very bottom of build.gradle file. Otherwise the app may crash when a message is being received.